# How to parse XML from a URL into an excel sheet?

Tags: python-3.x

I have written this code to parse data from XML in a URL I access from an API. I want to write this data into an excel sheet that updates on a set time period. How would I go about doing this?

```
import urllib.request
import xml.sax

class GoogleHandler(xml.sax.ContentHandler):
def characters(self, content):
print(content)


def startElement(self, name, attrs):
if name == ('name'):
    print("Location:", attrs)
Day.append(attrs)
if name == ("region"):
    print("Region:", attrs)
region.append(attrs)
if name == ("temp_f"):
    print("Temperature:", attrs)
temp.append(attrs)
if name == ("date"):
    print("Date:", attrs)
Date.append(attrs)
if name == ("maxtemp_f"):
    print("MaxTemp:", attrs)
MaxTemp.append(attrs)
if name == ("mintemp_f"):
    print("MinTemp:", attrs)
MinTemp.append(attrs)
if name == ("text"):
    print("Conditions:", attrs)
Condition.append(attrs)
if name == ("icon"):
    print("Icon:", attrs)
Condition.append(attrs)

xmlResponse = urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.xml?key=b87cee31cb6e4bea8c6163500192101&q=45242&days=7')

parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
parser.setContentHandler(GoogleHandler())
parser.parse(xmlResponse)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have some example data.

Answer (score 0):

### Requests

To get the data from the url, you can use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library, you will implement something like:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
data = r.content # or r.text if you do not want binary data
```

If xml is not mandatory, maybe you could also use the `r.json()` method to get the response as json.

### XML

There are many libraries in python to parse xml files, I generally use the [lxml](https://lxml.de/) library

### Excel

To write the output in excel, again there are many libs, you can use [Python-Excel](http://www.python-excel.org/).

### Schedule

To schedule the execution of your script, you could set a cron-job (or a scheduled task on windows) to run it when you want.